# Leer un Archivo y Dividirlo por Paginas PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, archivo, paginación

Buena tengo la porcion de codigo para hacer lectura de un archivo y mostrarla

```
$file = fopen("../assets/libros/el_libro_de_la_sabiduria/cap_01.htm", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$getline = '';

while(!feof($file))
{
    $getline .= fgets($file). "<br />";
}
$getfile = utf8_encode($getline);
echo '<pre>';
echo $getfile;
echo '</pre>';
fclose($file);
```

Este codigo retoma todo el archivo. Lo que quisiera saber es. Como puedo hacer para leer el archivo en partes?

Es decir, que me divida el archivo por paginas (Pag.1, Pag.2, Pag.3, etc), y yo poder mediante enlaces, acceder a ellos.

Muchas Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan prestar de antemano.

La data se envia y recibe por medio de ajax.

> EDIT: Basicamente, divir el archivo y crear paginaciones para ir pasando (Pagina por pagina) hasta finalizar el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
session_start();
// valida que este definida si lo esta toma su valor si no es 0
$_session["lines"] = $_session["lines"] ?? 0; 
$limit =10;   // envia de solo 10 lineas

$file = fopen("../assets/libros/el_libro_de_la_sabiduria/cap_01.htm", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$getline = '';

while(!feof($file))
{

    $getline .= fgets($file). "<br/>";
}
$getfile = utf8_encode($getline);
echo '<pre>';
// creamos un arreglo en base a las lineas que alla
$lineas = explode("<br>",$getfile)
//validamos que queden lineas para leer
if(count($lineas) <= $_session["lines"]){
// imprimimos solo las posiciones de 0 a 10 o 11 a 20
echo array_slice($lineas, $_session["lines"], $_session["lines"]+$limit);
$_session["lines"]=($_session["lines"]+$limit)+1;
echo '</pre>';
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: me devuelve:


Notice: Undefined variable: _session in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\php\funciones.php on line 57
0Array ( [lines] => 0 )

A pesar que la he declarado y me arroja en echo la session:

$_session["lines"] = $_session["lines"] ? $_session["lines"] : 0;
    echo  $_session["lines"];
    print_r($_session);